# Allowing an attribute-set to set a namespace required by an attribute

Tags: xslt, saxon

I understand that `xsl:attribute-set` exists to allow a set of XML attributes to be grouped under a single name, which can then then easily be applied to several similar elements at a later date.

I understand that namespaces are not attributes and cannot be set using this.

However in Saxon9.8EE I note this works and I was wondering if this is safe to use:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="swbml.ir" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:attribute name="version">4-2</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2 /path/to/swbml-ird-main-4-2.xsd</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

By adding the xsi namespace to the `xsl:attribute-set` itself, it applies this namespace to any element using the `swbml.ir` attribute set.

(of course it has to because one of the attributes sits in the xsi namespace)

So this:

```
<SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="swbml.ir">
```

Results in:

```
<SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       version="4-2"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2 /path/to/swbml-ird-main-4-2.xsd">
```

This is exactly what I want.  But it feels like I might be stretching the intended use-case for attribute sets?

Specifically if I try to go one step further and add `xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2"` like so:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="swbml.ir" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2">
```

The default xmlns is not applied to `<SWBML>` - which is kinda what I expect.

So - is the rule that attribute sets will add any namespace that is required in order to qualify any attribute the set contains, BUT will not add any other namespace?  Or have I strayed into undefined territory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct, in that if there is content bound to a namespace, and you include it in your output, then the namespace will come along for the ride. However, the fact that you happen to have declared it on the attribute-set is not critical. It could be declared in other places in the stylesheet, such as on the xsl:stylesheet element, to be in-scope and referenced in the attribute-set.

Building upon the examples that you posed, you could move the declaration of the `xsi` namespace prefix out of the `xsl:attribute-set` and up to the `xsl:stylesheet` element, and it would still appear in your output if the attribute-set were applied to the element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="swbml.ir">
        <xsl:attribute name="version">4-2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2 /path/to/swbml-ird-main-4-2.xsd</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" xsl:use-attribute-sets="swbml.ir"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it would not appear in the output if the attribute-set is not applied to the content:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="swbml.ir">
        <xsl:attribute name="version">4-2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2 /path/to/swbml-ird-main-4-2.xsd</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SWBML xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2005/FpML-4-2" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I used `exclude-result-prefixes` in both examples to ensure that the `xsi` namepsace is pruned from the output if unused. Otherwise, the in-scope namespace might come along for the ride in the output, even if it were not applied to any content.

Comment: Thanks!  One follow-up question - I get that I can have the namespace set at any node and it will still come along for the ride.  Is there a way to apply a namespsace to a group of `attribute-set`s within XSLT - i.e. have a scoped section of the XSLT document containing only `attribute-sets` where all children have the namespace applied.  Normally with XML output - you just add the `xmlns` to the output XML - easy, but `attribute-set`s can sit outside of any `template`, or even in a separate include?  Obviously I can set it atthe `xsl:stylesheet` level, but I want to nest below this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work: as @MadsHansen points out, when you use `<xsl:attribute name="p:u"/>` the only thing that really matters is that the prefix `p` is declared somewhere - on the `xsl:attribute` element itself, or on one of its ancestors. If it's convenient to declare it at the level of the `xsl:attribute-set` itself, then fine, do that.

A thing to watch out for here is that this doesn't apply to QName-valued attributes. If you want to do

```
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">xs:date</xsl:attribute>
```

then you can get the prefix `xsi` declared in the result document simply by having it in-scope for the `xsl:attribute` instruction, but for the `xs` prefix you need to work a bit harder (because the XSLT processor doesn't know that the attribute value xs:date is a QName). In this case you need to explicitly ensure that some containing element in the result tree declares the `xs` namespace.